# Cómo reducir una matriz cuadrada que tiene algunas filas y columnas cero

Tags: matriz, basic

En mi código algunas filas y columnas se tienen que hacer cero según el tipo de problema que se tenga de las estructuras, entonces en la matriz cuadrada que me genera tengo que eliminar esas filas y columnas cero para poder aplicar algún método de iteración para tratar de que obtenga los desplazamientos según las fuerzas aplicadas, pero se me esta complicando plantear el código para eliminar filas y columnas en una matriz, me podrían ayudar a estructurar algún código para eliminar esos ceros por favor soy estudiante de Ing. civil y en mi universidad vemos muy poco de programación, me pudieran ayudar en obtener ese segmento de código para poder reducir mi matriz.

```
For i25,1,pgl,1
  For i26,1,pgl-numgres,1
    If vgl[i25,1]=0 Then
      subm:=subMat(mg,i25,1,i25,pgl)
      mgc1:=newMat(pgl,pgl)
      mgc1[i25]:=subm
    ElseIf vgl[i26,1]≠0 Then
      subm:=subMat(mg,i25,1,i25,pgl)
      Disp "SUBM: ",subm
      mgc[i25-i26+1]:=subm
      Exit
      Disp "No se ensambla"
    EndIf
  EndFor
```